# Error while running docker compose command. WordPress is already installed

Tags: errors, docker, wp-env

Im in wp env environment and after this command

npm run env:start

> ekr-gutenberg@0.1.0 env:start
> wp-env start && ./php-extension.sh
>
> ✖ Error while running docker compose command. WordPress is already
> installed. Success: Updated the constant 'FS_METHOD' in the
> 'wp-config.php' file with the value 'direct'. Success: Updated the
> constant 'WP_DEBUG' in the 'wp-config.php' file with the raw value
> 'true'. Success: Updated the constant 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' in the
> 'wp-config.php' file with the raw value 'true'. Success: Updated the
> constant 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE' in the 'wp-config.php' file with the
> value 'local'. Success: Updated the constant 'WP_PHP_BINARY' in the
> 'wp-config.php' file with the value 'php'. Success: Updated the
> constant 'WP_TESTS_EMAIL' in the 'wp-config.php' file with the value
> 'admin@example.org'. Success: Updated the constant 'WP_TESTS_TITLE' in
> the 'wp-config.php' file with the value 'Test Blog'. Success: Updated
> the constant 'WP_TESTS_DOMAIN' in the 'wp-config.php' file with the
> value 'localhost:8888'. Success: Updated the constant 'WP_SITEURL' in
> the 'wp-config.php' file with the value 'http://localhost:8888'.
> Success: Updated the constant 'WP_HOME' in the 'wp-config.php' file
> with the value 'http://localhost:8888'.  Container
> 221cb3b2fc87677b60f0edba623fa904-mysql-1  Running  Container
> 221cb3b2fc87677b60f0edba623fa904-wordpress-1  Running

I have this error, the containers seems to run correctly but I have this error.

These are my dependencies and my script:

```
{
"scripts": {
    "test:docker": "wp-scripts test-e2e ",
    "test:unit": "wp-scripts test-unit-js --config jest.config.js",
    "env:start": "wp-env start && ./php-extension.sh",
    "env:stop": "wp-env stop",
    "env:destroy": "wp-env destroy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@uiw/codemirror-extensions-langs": "^4.19.16",
    "@uiw/react-codemirror": "^4.19.16",
    "@wordpress/components": "^22.0.0",
    "@wordpress/data": "^7.5.0",
    "@wordpress/e2e-test-utils": "^10.19.0",
    "@wordpress/edit-post": "^6.18.0",
    "@wordpress/env": "^9.0.0",
    "@wordpress/eslint-plugin": "^13.8.0",
    "@wordpress/i18n": "^4.24.0",
    "@wordpress/icons": "^9.12.0",
    "@wordpress/jest-console": "^7.19.0",
    "@wordpress/jest-puppeteer-axe": "^6.19.0",
    "@wordpress/plugins": "^4.19.0",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^24.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "css-modules": "^0.3.0",
    "expect-puppeteer": "^9.0.2",
    "fundamental-react": "^0.14.4",
    "ignore-emit-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.6",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.56.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "showdown": "^2.1.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  }
}
```

./php-extension.sh it's a script file to install some php extensions as explain in this article :

https://juzhax.com/2021/08/installing-php-extension-in-wp-env/